# MoovWeb: Redirect loop when visit m.site.com using en emulator or mobile device

Tags: moovweb

I am kind of new to moovweb. We have a site hosted locally. When we access m.site.com using Chrome or IE, I am able to see the mobile version of the site. However, when I use an emulator in Chrome or IE, I get a 'redirect loop' message.

Do you know what could cause this redirect loop?

Is this a configuration setting issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Can we see the code?

Comment: My guess is when you're testing on browser you're not setting the user agent to mobile. That's why you're not running into the redirect loop.
How are you handling redirection? You need to make sure the request coming from Moovweb is not being redirected. Moovweb adds "Via: 1.0 Moovweb" header so that you can identify Moovweb requests.

Comment: Hi, that is correct. I was not handling properly the request when it came from Moovweb and this caused the request being redirected. I checked for the Moovweb header 'Via: 1.0 Moovweb'. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Cagri's comment I was able to figure out what the issue was.

It turns out that I was not handling properly the request when it came from Moovweb and this caused the request being redirected. I checked for the Moovweb header 'Via: 1.0 Moovweb'.

Thanks